# Smart cards and firewalls are what type of access control?

Tags: access-control, cissp

Specifically for the CISSP, trying to figure out what type of access control these would be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Both smart cards and firewalls would be considered technical access controls.

There are **three types of access control** as defined by ISC2, **technical**, **administrative**, and **physical**. Physical includes badge readers, physical locks, etc. Administrative would be policies or procedures about access. Technical includes hardware or software systems which provide access control.

Answer (score -1):

The above is correct, but my understanding is that they could also could be considered a physical control.  "If you can hit your head on it, or drop it on your foot, it's a physical control".  If you have an actual rack mounted firewall, for example, that device is a physical control.  The software inside would be a technical control.